# Rewrite first query

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, query-string

Is it possible to rewrite a url, and still be able to use query?

I mean something like this: `http://domain.com/?page=Home&derp=true`

and rewrite it to this: `http://domain.com/home.htm?derp=true`

So actually just rewrite the first query...

I've tried to do this:

`RewriteRule ^([a-z]+).htm$ index.php?page=$1`

But Wasn't able to pass a parameter with D:

Comment: Are you just asking if the value of derp will still be passed if the URL is re-written? If so, then the answer to your question is `yes`.

Comment: @Evan Just couldn't get it to work earlier, soo, how do you do it?

Comment: @Moiblpadde You've asked questions here before. So at those questions that are answered, make sure to check the green box left of the answer that answered your question.

Comment: @Thew So, now, the questions that I havn't accepted, is because nobody was able to help me...

Comment: @Moiblpadde I know that feeling bro... So those questions are still unanswered? If you have an answer you found elsewhere, post it there also and accept it.

Comment: Nope, havn't found an answer anywhere else, and nobody seems to knwo it D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dude, you should better write your question. Just add [`[QSA]`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) at the end and it should work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+).htm$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

---

It's no problem at all, that are just some simple string operations in PHP, you don't even need a regular expression for it:

```
function rewrite_url($url) {
    list($prefix, $query) = explode('?', $url, 2) + array('','');
    parse_str($query, $vars);
    if (isset($vars['page'])) {
        $prefix .= $vars['page'] . '.htm';
        unset($vars['page'];
    }
    return $prefix . '?' . http_ build_ query($vars);
}
```

If you want to, you can do this with regex, too:

```
$url = preg_replace('/^(.*)$/e', 'rewrite_url(\'$1\')', $url);
```

Comment: @Moiblpadde: No problem, I added how this is done in regex to the answer. You've removed PHP, so I don't know which kind of regex you actually mean, naturally I keep using PHP as you announced originally.

Comment: Sorry (again), I meant rewrite (in .htaccess) D: Thats ok, I don't why I added the php. (Mostly because almost all of my questions are about php)

Comment: Well, next time make more clear what you actually want to know. Describe what does not work for you (not what you think the solution must be) ;)

Answer (score 0):

For URL rewriting consider using Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) engine

If mod_rewrite is not an answer consider explaining your application's logic, framework you'r using and other details at least.

Comment: I'm using mod_rewrite... I just don't know how to do it D: (Updated my question)